# How to find the principal axis of the pieces of lens after billetsplit cutting?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

[image]I was reading about lens from a book . There I couldn't make about the principal axis for billetsplit cutting of lens . As it can be seen from the above image that two lines L1 and L2 are drawn and claimed to be the principal axis of the cutted lens . But how are the lines drawn ? Please help me in understanding it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cut is infinitely thin and goes right on the principal axis of the lens, L1 and L2 run in the plane of the cut.  Imagine that the original principal axis is split into two thin lines instead of one, each of the two staying stuck to its own half of the lens.  Then the two halves of the lens are moved apart, dragging the thin lines along.  Those are the principal axes of the two halves.