# mathematically, what exactly is the principal axis of a lens?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

while solving problems on ray optics, I came across a problem in which a lens is cut along a line that DOESN'T pass via the optical center. [this answer on bisplit cutting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554277/how-to-find-the-principal-axis-of-the-pieces-of-lens-after-billetsplit-cutting)

But it doesn't really help me

Comment: In elementary work (and quite possibly in more advanced treatments) the principal axis is the straight line passing through the centres of curvature of the two lens faces. This line is unaffected by cutting bits out of the lens.

Comment: I see, thanks!!